# Hibernate syntax error: Attribute "column" must be declared for element type "column"

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I'm an experienced Java-developer but have just started using Hibernate am doing something (probably multiple things) wrong in my class-xml. Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping> 
<class name="database.entities.LineItem" table="algorithms_in_production"> 
<composite-id>
    <key-many-to-one name="algorithm" class="database.entities.Algorithm"  column="algorithm_id" />
    <key-many-to-one name="instrument" class="database.entities.Instrument" column="instrument_id" > </key-many-to-one>
    <key-many-to-one name="underlyings" class="database.entities.Underlyings" column="underlyings_id" > </key-many-to-one>
    <key-many-to-one name="setting" class="database.entities.AlgorithmSetting" column="setting_id" > </key-many-to-one>
</composite-id>

<many-to-one name="algorithmStatistic" class="Algorithm" fetch="join" unique="true" />

<property name="dateInProduction" column="date_in_production" type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime"/> 
<property name="dateOutProduction" column="date_out_production" type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime"/> 

</class> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And this is the xml for the Algorithm-class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN" 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping> 
<class name="database.entities.Algorithm" table="algorithms"> 
<id name="algorithmId" type="int" column="algorithm_id"> 
    <generator class="native"/> 
</id> 

<property name="algorithmTypeId" column="algorithm_type_id" type="int"/> 
<property name="name" column="name" type="String"/> 

</class> </hibernate-mapping>
```

And this is the relevant part of the classes:

```
public class LineItem {
    private Algorithm algorithm;
    private Instrument instrument;
    private Underlyings underlyings;
    private AlgorithmSetting setting;
    private AlgorithmStatistic algorithmStatistic;
    List<AlgorithmReturn> algorithmReturns;
    private DateTime dateInProduction;
    private DateTime dateOutProduction;
...


public class Algorithm {
private int algorithmId;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private int algorithmTypeId;
private String name;
...
```

And here is the table that I'm mapping the LineItem-class to:

```
`Table "public.algorithms_in_production"
Column              |            Type             | Modifiers
---------------------+-----------------------------+-----------
algorithm_id        | integer                     | not null
instrument_id       | integer                     | not null
underlyings_id      | integer                     | not null
setting_id          | integer                     | not null
date_in_production  | timestamp without time zone | not null
date_out_production | timestamp without time zone |
"pk_algorithms_in_production" PRIMARY KEY, btree (algorithm_id, instrument_id, underlyings_id, setting_id)`
```

- Algorithm is a class that is mapped uniquely to algorithm_id.
- Instrument is a class that is mapped uniquely to instrument_id.
- Underlyings is a class that is mapped uniquely to underlyings_id.
- AlgorithmSetting is a class that is mapped uniquely to setting_id.
- AlgorithmStatistic is a class that is mapped uniquely to the primary key in the table above.
- AlgorithmReturn is a class that is mapped uniquely to the primary key in the table above plus a timestamp. The list should hold all the instances that maps to the primary key.

Here is the stackstrace:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table algorithms_in_production refers to an unmapped class: Algorithm
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at taipan.database.helpers.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:23)
    at taipan.database.aggregators.LineItemsInProduction.getLineItems(LineItemsInProduction.java:77)
    at taipan.main.BacktestingFictive.main(BacktestingFictive.java:75)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table algorithms_in_production refers to an unmapped class: Algorithm
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(Configuration.java:1824)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1756)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1423)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1856)
    at taipan.database.helpers.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:19)
    ... 2 more
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Not really sure, but probably a typo: `date_in_oroduction` should be `date_in_production`

Comment: Good catch! Corrected that but get exactly the same error message

Comment: From the xml point of view: In the elements named 'column' you use the attributes 'column' and 'type'. They are not defined in the [declared namespace](http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd). But I've no idea how the binding is done instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've updated the question with the current error message that I can't seem to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whole mapping seems to be more or less broken - for example following:

- attribute `class` is not aloud for element `key-property`
- attribute `column` is not aloud for element `column`
- element `many-to-one` should be closed with `many-to-one`, not with `one-to-many`.
- element `many-to-one` cannot contain composite-id
- `property` is not allowed child of `many-to-one`
- `property` element should not have `table` and `cascade` attributes.

For continuing it makes sense to:

1. Study Hibernate reference manual - [Chapter 5. Basic O/R Mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html) in detail and take a look to other chapters as well.
2. Use DTD aware editor that provides validation and auto-completion.

Comment: I think hibernate-mapping is closed? OK, I'll have another look there

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've updated the question with the current error message that I can't seem to figure out.

Comment: That's right hibernate-mapping was closed already. Now attribute class is missing full package, database.entities.Algorithm should be used instead.